# How to test a vue method with mocha Chai

Tags: vue.js, webpack, mocha.js, chai

This is MOCHA CHAI unit test : users.spec.js :

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Users from "@/components/Users.vue";

const wrapper = shallowMount(Users);

describe("Users test", () => {
  it("Displays nice hello message", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.msg).to.equal("Welcome to Crypto Info");
  });
  it("users model is an array", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.users).to.be.an("array");
  });
  it("getUsers() to be a function", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$methods.getUsers()).to.be.a("function");
  });
});
```

I can't find the correct syntax for my third test . I've tried plenty of things . $methods.getUsers() is not working .

```
  1) Users test
   getUsers() to be a function:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUsers' of undefined
  at Context.it (dist\js\webpack:\tests\unit\users.spec.js:15:1)
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you .

Comment: Testing whether the method exists doesn't seem like a useful test. A more effective test would be to verify the result of the method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method would simply be defined as a property of the `wrapper.vm`, so you could verify the method exists with:

```js
expect(wrapper.vm.getUsers).to.be.a("function")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ill try out this today!

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like

```
const result = typeOf wrapper.vm.$methods.getUsers();
```

Then test the result is a string with value "function"?

```
expect(result).to.equal("function");
```

Is that any use to you?

Comment: Thanks I will try this out today too and let you know !